# Python string index and character comparing

Tags: python, string, search, slice

So i'm trying to do something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char string[] = "bobgetbob";
    int i = 0, count = 0;
    for(i; i < 10; ++i)
    {
            if(string[i] == 'b' && string[i+1] == 'o' && string[i+2] == 'b')
                    count++;
    }
    printf("Number of 'bobs' is: %d\n",count);

}
```

but in python terms which works like this

```
count = 0
s = "bobgetbob"
for i in range(0,len(s)):
    if s[i] == 'b' and s[i+1] == 'o' and s[i+2] == 'b':
        count += 1
print "Number of 'bobs' is: %d" % count
```

anytime I get a string that so happens to end with a 'b' or the second to last is 'b' followed by a 'o' I get an index out of range error. Now in c this is not an issue because it will still perform the comparison with a garbage value i'm assuming which works with c.

How do I go about doing this in python without going outside of the range?

Could i iterate through the string itself like so?

```
for letter in s:
    #compare stuff
```

How would I compare specific indexes in the string using the above method? if I try to use

```
letter == 'b' and letter + 1 == 'o'
```

this is invalid syntax in python, my issue is i'm thinking in terms of c and I'm not completely sure of the right syntax to tackle this situation.
I know about string slicing like so

```
for i in range(0,len(s)):
    if s[i:i+3] == "bob":
        count += 1
```

this solves this specific problem but, I feel like using specific index positions to compare characters is a very powerful tool. I can't figure out for the life of me how to properly do this in python without having some situations that break it like the first python example above.

Comment: I just realized that if I know the length of the word i'm searching for, I can just limit the range of the string i'm searching through so I don't go out of bounds. For example since bob is three letters long there is no point in checking the second to last letter in a for loop because bob has to be atleast 3 letters long i limit the range by two and the last letter I check is the third to last letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could i iterate through the string itself like so?
>
> ```
> for letter in s:
> #compare stuff
> ```
>
> How would I compare specific indexes in the string using the above method?

The pythonic way of doing these kind of comparisons without specifically referring to indexes would be:

```
for curr, nextt, nexttt in zip(s, s[1:], s[2:]):
    if curr == 'b' and nextt == 'o' and nexttt == 'b':
         count += 1
```

This avoids out of index errors. You can also use a comprehension and in this way you eliminate the need to initialize and update the `count` variable. This line will do the same as your C code:

```
>>> sum(1 for curr, nextt, nexttt in zip(s, s[1:], s[2:])
          if curr == 'b' and nextt == 'o' and nexttt == 'b')
2
```

**How it works:** 
This is the result of the zip between the lists:

```
>>> s
'bobgetbob'
>>> s[1:]
'obgetbob'
>>> s[2:]
'bgetbob'

>>> zip(s, s[1:], s[2:])
[('b', 'o', 'b'),
 ('o', 'b', 'g'),
 ('b', 'g', 'e'),
 ('g', 'e', 't'),
 ('e', 't', 'b'),
 ('t', 'b', 'o'),
 ('b', 'o', 'b')]
```

In the loop you iterate the list unpacking each of the tuples to the three variables.

Finally, if you really need the index you can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> for i, c in enumerate(s):
        print i, c   
0 b
1 o
2 b
3 g
4 e
5 t
6 b
7 o
8 b
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, that is the slow way to do it; you are better off delegating as much as possible to higher-performance object methods like `str.find`:

```
def how_many(needle, haystack):
    """
    Given
        needle:   str to search for
        haystack: str to search in

    Return the number of (possibly overlapping)
      occurrences of needle which appear in haystack

    ex,  how_many("bb", "bbbbb")  => 4
    """
    count = 0
    i = 0      # starting search index
    while True:
        ni = haystack.find(needle, i)
        if ni != -1:
            count += 1
            i = ni + 1
        else:
            return count

how_many("bob", "bobgetbob")    # => 2
```

---

`haystack.find(needle, i)` returns the start index of the next occurrence of `needle` beginning on or after index `i`, or `-1` if there is no such occurrence.

So

```
"bobgetbob".find("bob", 0)    # returns 0    => found 1
"bobgetbob".find("bob", 1)    # returns 6    => found 1
"bobgetbob".find("bob", 7)    # returns -1   => no more
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this - i.e. go to len(s)-2 as you won't ever get a bob starting after that point

```
count = 0
s = "bobgetbob"
for i in range(len(s) - 2):
    if s[i] == 'b' and s[i + 1] == 'o' and s[i + 2] == 'b':
        count += 1
print "Number of 'bobs' is: %d" % count
```

Answer (score 1):

a generator expression and sum would be a better way to solve it:

```
print("number of bobs {}".format(sum(s[i:i+3] == "bob" for i in xrange(len(s)) )))
```

You can also cheat a bit with indexing i.e `s[i+2:i+3]` will not throw an indexError :

```
count = 0
s = "bobgetbob"
for i in range(0,len(s)):
    print(s[i+1:i+1])
    if s[i] == 'b' and s[i+1:i+2] == 'o' and s[i+2:i+3] == 'b':
        count += 1
print "Number of 'bobs' is: %d" % count
Number of 'bobs' is: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0
for i in range(0,len(s)-2):
    if s[i] == 'b' and s[i+1] == 'o' and s[i+2] == 'b':
        count += 1
print "Number of 'bobs' is: %d" % count
```